# When citing web sources, should I give the URL within the text itself?

Tags: citations

When I am citing web sources, should I give the URL within the text itself?

Comment: Some URLs are insanely long and difficult to understand, especially if served by a database. Be careful that you don't insert essentially meaningless things that distract the reader.

Comment: Please add more details. A GitHub repo? absoutely. a nonsense url like buffs mentions, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, web sources have an author and a publication/creation date as well. These you can add in-text, and then put Author, Year, Title, website and retrieval date in the reference list.